# How to reduce duplication when writing traits for reference and non reference types when the traits are the same

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-meta-programming

I have for example

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct Base {};

template <>
struct Base<std::string> {
  static const int value = true;
};

template <>
struct Base<std::string &> {
  static const int value = true;
};

int main() {
  bool a = Base<std::string>::value;
  bool b = Base<std::string &>::value;

  std::cout << a << b << std::endl;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/0NpYxB

Note I have two specializations that are identical and would like to reduce it to one. There are two solutions I know of which I'd prefer not to do.

(1) Remove the reference at the call site so that only one specialization is required.

(2) Create a base class and inherit the **reference** and **no reference** versions from that.

Is there a third option where the specialization is generic over reference and non reference types?

C++11 solutions are required.

Comment: (3) inherit reference from no reference (or vice versa).

Comment: Thankyou. 2 classes  is better than defining 3 classes but it is still two classes. I'd like to try for one only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform the check in SFINAE context:

```
// type trait to remove the lvalue-reference
template< class T > struct remove_lvalue_reference      {typedef T type;};
template< class T > struct remove_lvalue_reference<T&>  {typedef T type;};

template <typename T>
using remove_lvalue_reference_t = typename remove_lvalue_reference<T>::type;

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct Base {};

// valid when T is std::string and std::string&
template <typename T>
struct Base<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<std::string, remove_lvalue_reference_t<T>>::value>::type> {
  static const int value = true;
};
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/NbUutXkvKHAmZ12C)

Comment: I came up with the same answer after I thought about it myself a bit. :)

Comment: or possibly `std::is_same<std::string, T>::value || std::is_same<std::string&, T>::value`.

Comment: When I went back to my code to implement this I found that I had simplified too much. The real problem is trying to use SFINAE on this https://godbolt.org/z/IhGSEe but I don't think it will be possible.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing How about [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/PbshBoE8vRKw2yTP)? (It seems much more complex although...)

Comment: Yes I guess it does work. However it's now past the threshold of being more complex than just the base class and inherit with two cases. But thanks for the effort :)

Answer (score 3):

1) Seems fine:

```
template <typename T>
struct BaseImpl {};

template <>
struct BaseImpl<std::string> {
  static const int value = true;
};

template <typename T>
using Base = BaseImpl<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>;
```

2) Seems more verbose

```
template <typename T>
struct BaseImpl {};

template <>
struct BaseImpl<std::string> {
  static const int value = true;
};

template <typename T>
struct Base : BaseImpl<T> {}; // or directly BaseImpl<std::remove_reference_t<T>>

template <typename T>
struct Base<T&> : BaseImpl<T> {};
```

3) Similar to 2), less verbose, but might be more tricky

```
template <typename T>
struct Base : Base<T&> {};

template <typename T>
struct Base<T&> {};

template <>
struct Base : Base<std::string> {
    static const int value = true;
};
```

1) seems the more readable, simple to implement.

Comment: `using Base = BaseImpl<std::remove_reference_t<T>>;` should be `using Base = BaseImpl<typename std::remove_reference<T>>;` since the OP is limited to C++11 but otherwise +1 for option 1

Comment: @NathanOliver: Oh, didn't see C++11 tag.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit heavy with enable_if but I don't think there is a better way.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename Enable = void>
struct Base {};


template <typename T>
struct Base<
    T,
    typename std::enable_if< 
       std::is_same<typename std::decay<T>::type, std::string>::value
    >::type 
>
{
  static const int value = true;
};

int main() {
  bool a = Base<std::string>::value;
  bool b = Base<std::string &>::value;

  std::cout << a << b << std::endl;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/98vzFN